# EF Core - Relationship between 2 entities for non-PK columns

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

Here are my simplified entities for this questions:

```
public class Page
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PageType { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public string CmsContentId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<CmsContentLanguage> Languages { get; set; }
}

public class CmsContentLanguage
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string LangugeCode { get; set; }
    public string CmsContentId { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is query my Page table and include the Sections navigation property, and for each Section the Languages property (which is not a db column) will be a collection of CmsContentLanguages. The response from my query would look like this:

```
{
   "id":"6b3c680a-a5aa-4782-80ce-591f1d16abe2",
   "pageName":"Description",
   "pageType":"content",
   "sections":[
      {
         "id":"e688b09e-9b1c-4094-aa04-cd044c820630",
         "sectionName":"Introduction",
         "cmsContentId ":"e1ad5dca-c74b-497e-856b-bf26a699e635",
         "languages":[
            {
               "id":"11e19169-797c-4b6a-b5e8-2bdb9c1f28cc",
               "languageCode":"en",
               "cmsContentId ":"e1ad5dca-c74b-497e-856b-bf26a699e635"
            },
            {
               "id":"19a0f31c-4b96-4afe-920f-40cea544eeab",
               "languageId":"es",
               "cmsContentId ":"e1ad5dca-c74b-497e-856b-bf26a699e635"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"a53b9ace-b9a7-407d-b641-7a3c46077428",
         "sectionName":"FAQs",
         "cmsContentId ":"e1ad5dca-c74b-497e-856b-bf26a699e635",
         "languages":[
            {
               "id":"11e19169-797c-4b6a-b5e8-2bdb9c1f28cc",
               "languageCode":"en",
               "cmsContentId ":"e1ad5dca-c74b-497e-856b-bf26a699e635"
            },
            {
               "id":"19a0f31c-4b96-4afe-920f-40cea544eeab",
               "languageId":"es",
               "cmsContentId ":"e1ad5dca-c74b-497e-856b-bf26a699e635"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Multiple Section records can have the same CmsContentId value. Section.Languages is not a navigation property (nor do I think it should be).

Then I want to do a Linq query like this:

```
            var guidId = Guid.Parse("6b3c680a-a5aa-4782-80ce-591f1d16abe2");
            var query = dbContext.Pages
                .Include(x => x.Sections)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == guidId);
```

At this point I have the response data I want, but the Languages property of each Section entity is null. This is where I'm lost as to how to setup relationships or do a query to get this data.

Comment: So do that via `Select` without Includes.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but it it too vague for me to understand. Select what and where? The dbContext.Pages query returns a page entity, which is what I want.

Comment: I guess `Section.CmsContentId` must be configured as alternate key. Then you can create a *mapped* navigation property `Languages`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `ThenInclude` method. Here is how you use it.

```cs
var query = dbContext.Pages
    .Include(x => x.Sections)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Languages)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == guidId);
```

Comment: This works if there is a relationship between Sections and CmsContentLanguage entities. And that relationship, if configured, would have to be on the non-primary key (CmsContentId field). Do you know how you could configure that relationship?

Comment: @Jeffrey If you are asking for how to configure foreign key relationships with EF Core, check out the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key